# How do I avoid infinite loop in my survey java project?

Tags: infinite-loop, infinite, survey

I've just jumped to the programming field. Please help me to find a reasonable solution to one of my educational projects. In case of incorrect input (for example 'z' in place of a figure) my program starts an infinite loop. I'm looking for the alternative to the infinite loop and catch use. At least, maybe someone could suggest how to empty the tray (the methods available on this site don't work with my Win7, NetBeans IDE 7.4).

OBJECTIVE 
Develop a program that allows the determination of a specific number of metrics obtained in a survey.

Data
A company sponsors you for the realization of a survey system to a target prospects. According to data collected on individuals during the day, we can calculate metrics that can help the company to better target customers.

The questions used for the survey are:

Question 1: Did you like to use our product?

Question 2: If the answer to question 1 is yes, you will continue to use our product?

Question 3: Do you plan to use a product of our competitor?

Question 4: On a scale of 1 to 3 (1: bad, 2 neutral, 3 good), how do you consider the reputation of our company?

The specific task is to determine the percentages for each question. For questions 1 to 3, percentages of YES and NO are required. For question 4 the percentages of each possible choice are needed.

The data is stored in a single memory structure during the course of the program. By late afternoon, an agent terminates the program after outputting data. Therefore, we will not persist on files or databases for the moment.

Data or metrics will be posted later in the day in a clear format.

So, the purpose is to realize the capture and storage of data and to calculate metrics.

Here you are my Java code:

```
package surveyproject;

import java.util.Scanner;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SurveyProject {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);


        ArrayList TotalSurvey = new ArrayList();

        do {


               try
               {

                System.out.println("Welcome to survey !");

                 System.out.println("1 - New survey");
                 System.out.println("2 - Publish survey results");
                 System.out.println("3 - Leave the program");

                 int new_or_printing_results_or_exit = sc.nextInt(); 

                 if (new_or_printing_results_or_exit == 1)
                 {

                          // ============== Questions 1 and 2 ================ //

                            System.out.println("Do you use our product? 1-yes 0-no");

                             int Q1_using_product = sc.nextInt(); 

                             int Q2_using_product_in_future = -1; 

                             if (Q1_using_product == 1)
                             {
                                 System.out.println("Thanks to use our product. Will you "
                                         + "continue to use it? 1-yes 0-no");

                                 Q2_using_product_in_future = sc.nextInt();


                             }
                             else 
                             {
                                 System.out.println("That's a pity you do not use your product.");
                             }

                         // =====///====== Question 1 and 2 ================ //

                         // ============== Question 3 ================ //
                              System.out.println("Do you use the products of our competitors? 1-yes 0-no");

                                int Q3_using_competitor_product = sc.nextInt();
                         // =====///====== Question 3 ================ //    

                         // ============== Question 4 ================ //
                              System.out.println("Evaluate our company.");
                              System.out.println("1 - Bad");
                              System.out.println("2 - Neutral");
                              System.out.println("3 - Good");

                                int Q4_company_reputation_rate = sc.nextInt();
                         // =====///====== Question 4 ================ //

                         System.out.println("Thank you for the participation!");

                         // =========== Save current Survey =========== //


                         Survey objSurvey = new Survey(Q1_using_product, 
                                                          Q2_using_product_in_future,
                                                          Q3_using_competitor_product,
                                                          Q4_company_reputation_rate);

                         TotalSurvey.add(objSurvey);


                         // =====///=== Save current Survey =========== //

                 }
                 else if (new_or_printing_results_or_exit == 2)
                 {


                     PrintSurveyResult(TotalSurvey);


                 }
                 else if (new_or_printing_results_or_exit == 3)
                 {
                      System.out.println("Thank you to use our system!");

                      System.exit(0);
                 }

               }
               catch(Exception except)
               {
                   System.out.println("You entered incorrect answer. Please,"
                           + "try again the survey." );


                     System.out.println("Total answers: " + total_answers);

                     System.out.println("Question 1: ");
                     System.out.println("Yes answered: " + Q1_answer_yes + "(" + (double)Q1_answer_yes/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");
                     System.out.println("No answered: " + Q1_answer_no + "(" + (double)Q1_answer_no/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");


                     System.out.println("Question 2: ");
                     System.out.println("Yes answered: " + Q2_answer_yes + "(" + (double)Q2_answer_yes/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");
                     System.out.println("No answered: " + Q2_answer_no + "(" + (double)Q2_answer_no/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");


                     System.out.println("Question 3: ");
                     System.out.println("Yes answered: " + Q3_answer_yes + "(" + (double)Q3_answer_yes/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");
                     System.out.println("No answered: " + Q3_answer_no + "(" + (double)Q3_answer_no/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");


                     System.out.println("Question 4: ");
                     System.out.println("Bad answered: " + Q4_answer_bad + "(" + (double)Q4_answer_bad/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");
                     System.out.println("Neutral answered: " + Q4_answer_neutral + "(" + (double)Q4_answer_neutral/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");
                     System.out.println("Good answered: " + Q4_answer_good + "(" + (double)Q4_answer_good/total_answers * 100.0 + "%)");       
    }   
}


package surveyproject;

public class Survey {

    int Q1_using_product;
    int Q2_using_product_in_future;
    int Q3_using_competitor_product;
    int Q4_company_reputation_rate;


    public Survey (int Q1, int Q2, int Q3, int Q4)
    {
        Q1_using_product = Q1;
        Q2_using_product_in_future = Q2;
        Q3_using_competitor_product = Q3;
        Q4_company_reputation_rate = Q4;

    }


    public int getQ1_using_product()
    {
       return Q1_using_product;
    }

    public int getQ2_using_product_in_future()
    {
       return Q2_using_product_in_future;
    }

    public int getQ3_using_competitor_product()
    {
       return Q3_using_competitor_product;
    }

    public int getQ4_company_reputation_rate()
    {
       return Q4_company_reputation_rate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you paste only the relevant code?

Comment: your while has no abort condition. You should add something like `if (allAnswersValid) break;` or even better, just `do {...} while(!allAnswersValid)`